# how to add string replace space in ajax

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

need help where my ajax edit function

```
function edit_person(kdiklan)
{
    save_method = 'update';
    $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals
    $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // clear error class
    $('.help-block').empty(); // clear error string

    //Ajax Load data from ajax
    $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo site_url('person/ajax_edit/')?>/" + kdiklan,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data)
```

if the data show kdiklan like this its work

```
kdiklan
001009
001008
009345
```

but if my data show like this my code not work to get kdiklan

```
kdiklan
brand 001
CSS 899
```

cause the data have space between string and number
there any one expert for this problem?

Comment: pass the data like this  data:{kdiklan:kdiklan}

Comment: where i have to put that? in my ajax or in my controller?

Comment: $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo site_url('person/ajax_edit/')?>/",
        type: "GET", 
        dataType: "JSON",data:{kdiklan:kdiklan}

Comment: in controller access like this $_GET['kdiklan'];

Comment: im try using ur code my json list not show my data

Answer (score 2):

You have to use 'encodeURIComponent()' function from encode url.

```
    function edit_person(kdiklan)
    {

    save_method = 'update';
    $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals
    $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // clear error class
    $('.help-block').empty(); // clear error string
    kdiklan= encodeURIComponent(kdiklan);
    //Ajax Load data from ajax
    $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo site_url('person/ajax_edit/')?>/" + kdiklan,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data)
```

Comment: still not work not show my edit modal in response display null

Comment: So now you can pass `kdiklan` params using POST method.